Connecting PUMPKIN USB Debug Adapter to computer
I'm working with the PUMPKIN GNSS receiver, and I'm looking to connect the PUMPKIN USB adapter to try and figure out what's happening. The receiver's user manual says to "Open a terminal to the USB Debug Adapters’s Virtual COM port and configure it for the 115200,N,8,1." Does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks! Any help is appreciated.
I don't really have that much experience with using virtual COM ports at all, so I'm a little bit stuck.
